# Call jQuery function after ajax html get loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, call

So i have this 2 jQuery functions stored in a .js file and .js file is loaded before head tag

what is in .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'button2.php',
            success: 
                function(html){
                    $('#button_div').html(html)
                }
            ,
        });     
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'button1.php',
            success: 
                function(html){
                    $('#button_div').html(html)
                }
            ,
        });     
    });

});
```

So after body I have:

```
<div id="button_div"><input type="button" id="button1" value="Press"></div>
```

when the button1 is pressed will load php file named button2.php with the div and button2 code, but here when button2 is pressed will not execute the button2 click function.

Why?

If I put the jQuery code of button2 inside button2.php file after elements will work fine. But I don't want that. I want to keep the jQuery lines saved only in a .js file and only before `</head>` tag. I don't want to use jQuery lines after elements.

Comment: In first one `$(#button_div).html(html)` is missing quotes `$("#button_div").html(html)`. also these two ajax calls could be done with one and use button id to populate url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `$("#button2").click()`, `#button2` does not exist yet, so you are calling it on nothing.  In order to have the click event work, you need to use event delegation (i.e. bind to an element that *exists*) like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button2', function () {
```

Then, any time `#button2` gets added, clicking it will trigger that event callback.

(I use `document` as an example, but try to use an ancestor that is closer to `#button2` than that).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because your selector doesn't return an element when you first call it. `$('#button2')` is called only once and doesn't monitor the DOM for changes.

Use the event delegation syntax instead:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '#button2', function() {
    ...
});
```

Also your AJAX request can be simplified a little:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $('#button_div').load('button2.php');
});
```

Comment: I believe you just have it be `$("#button2").on("click", function () {});` right?

Comment: @JustinChmura: Not really. `.on()` isn't `.live()`. With the event delegation syntax, you're really binding the event handler to the parent element and then trickling down the event to the child element that matches the second selector.

Comment: @JustinChmura That is incorrect for the case where you want to handle click events when `#button2` does not exist yet.  You must use the event delegation syntax shown in this example.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the contents of both button1.php and button2.php i assume

button1.php=

```
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Press">
```

button2.php=

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Press">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Inside you button1 click function:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'button2.php',
        success: 
            function(html){
                $("#button_div").html(html) // You forgot pass the selector as a string
            }
        ,
    });     
});
```

This may fix your problem. Also, if your jQuery is being called before the element is created (remember it's top down), it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `#button2` does not exist on the page when you create the click handler.  You need to use `on()` with its support for delegated events to do what you are looking to do.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button2', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'button1.php',
        success: 
            function(html){
                $('#button_div').html(html)
            }
    });     
});
```

Ideally you could get an element that exists on the page prior to creation of `#button2` that contains `#button2` that you could attach the event handler to rather than `document`.